# How does CasperJs bind variables?

Tags: variables, binding, casperjs

I have the following code which does not post data as expected

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var myData;
var utils = require('utils');

casper.start();

casper.then(function () {
    myData = {"source":"casperjs"};
    utils.dump(myData);
});

casper.thenOpen('http://my-api/api/upload/', {
    method: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(myData),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }   
}, function () {
    utils.dump(myData);
});

casper.run();
```

The message was sent to my server but without valid data. However, if I move the *thenOpen(...)* into the *then(...)* like this

```
casper.then(function () {
    myData = {"source":"casperjs"};
    utils.dump(myData);
    this.thenOpen('http://my-api/api/upload/', {
        method: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    }, function () {
        utils.dump(myData);
    });
});
```

Then the post would succeed. Or If i change the *thenOpen* part in the original code (i.e., without moving it in to the *casper.then(...)* part, like this

```
casper.thenOpen('http://my-api/api/upload/', {
    method: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify({"source":"casperjs"}),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    }   
}, function () {
    utils.dump(myData);
});
```

Then the post would also be successful. So it looks like *myData* has to be initialized when the *thenOpen(...)* is seen. So is this expected or I have done something wrong? I could not find reference about this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior as casperjs schedules the steps before running them. This means for your first listing that `JSON.stringify(undefinded)` will be sent to the server. The reason is that your first `casper.then` block was not yet executed when the object is evaluated for your `casper.thenOpen` block. Therefore your data was not yet assigned properly to `myData`, which happens inside the step.

The evaluation of the POST data on the other hand is done *for* the `thenOpen` call and not inside, so it is executed synchronously.

You already provided some good alternatives.